# I wat to update the textboxes having id month_no and quarter automatically whenever a month i selected the month_no is updating but quarter isn't

Tags: c#, jquery, html, css

How i can automatically update the value in quarter text box like whenever the month is selected the month_no and quarter automatically updated in text boxes. i have two text boxes month_no is updating but quarter doesn't.

```
    jQuery(function($) {
        $("#month").change(function() {
            var selectedvalue=$(this).val();

            $("#month_no").val($(this)
                .find("option:selected").attr("value"))
            if(selectedvalue=="january" || selectedvalue=="Febraury" || selectedvalue=="March") {
                $("#quarter").val("q1");
            }
        });
    });
<asp:Label runat="server">Month</asp:Label>
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" Width="200px" CssClass="form-control" ID="month" OnTextChanged="change">
            <asp:ListItem Text="January" Value="January" Enabled="true"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Febraury" Value="Febraury" Enabled="true" Selected="False"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="March" Value="March" Enabled="true"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="April" Value="April" Enabled="true" Selected="False"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="May" Value="May" Enabled="true" Selected="False"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="June" Value="June" Enabled="true" Selected="False"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="July" Value="July" Enabled="true" Selected="False"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="August" Value="August" Enabled="true" Selected="False"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="September" Value="September" Enabled="true" Selected="False"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="October" Value="October" Enabled="true" Selected="False"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="November" Value="November" Enabled="true" Selected="False"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="December" Value="December" Enabled="true" Selected="False"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Label runat="server">Month NO</asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Width="200px" ID="month_no"
<asp:Label runat="server">quarter</asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Width="200px" ID="quarter"


<script>
```

Comment: Please include your html code

Comment: Show us the HTML.

Comment: dont you need a ; after the .find("option:selected").attr("value"))

Comment: included my html code .